# Lock ReentrantLock. Can't understand javadoc

Tags: java, locking

one thread call plus1, second- plus2. will be field first change?  Or will not it be available for thread which call second time lock()?

if plus2 don't call lock(), what value will be he use?

```
public class Test {

private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private int first;

public void plus1() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        first++;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public void plus2() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        first += 2;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public int getFirst() {
    return first;
}
```

}

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand (at least for me). Both `plus1` and `plus2` modify the `first` field, so it looks like the field will be modified twice, although not concurrently... it's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: In this case the lock doesn't need to be re-entrant. You don't call a method which uses the lock from another method which uses the lock. So one thread can never enter the lock twice within a call stack.

Comment: You also need to use the lock in getFirst() or else the changes made by the other methods may never be visible to the thread calling getFirst()

Answer (score 4):

If the second thread, that is calling `plus2()`, is starting execution after the first thread (i.e. the first thread currently executes `plus1()`) is would have to wait until the lock is freed (the `lock.lock()` method would block).

If `plus2()` wouldn't use the lock, it might either operate on the initial value of `first` (which would be 0) or on `first + 1`, depending on whether the assignment (which is implicit with post increment) occured or not. Thus you can't definitely tell which value of `first` would be used.

Answer (score 1):

> one thread call plus1, second- plus2. will be field first change? Or
>   will not it be available for thread which call second time lock()?

It depends which thread obtains the lock first. If the first thread gets the lock,the second thread will have to wait until the first one releases it.

> if plus2 don't call lock(), what value will be he use?

It is unpredictible. You can't tell. That's why you need locks to produce a deterministic result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both threads will change `first`. The point of the locking is that without the locks you might lose one of the updates.

The Reentrancy of the lock means that if Thread A has the lock it can lock it again. The locking/unlocking is nested.

If plus2 didnt use the lock then it might get the value before increment or after, there is no way of telling.

Comment: Thanks for reply) Now i'm more confident) 

if field first make AtomicInteger, his value  willn't update while some thread call unlock()?